# What does short_ping do?

Tags: seo

Since WP 3.6, you can do `short_ping` on comments as you can see 
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments.

I want to use it for my new website [ZorgWijzer.nl](http://www.zorgwijzer.nl), but I am not really sure if this is good or bad for SEO. Can someone tell me where I can find more information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If the comment is a pingback or a trackback and short_ping is `true`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1338) then the comment is processed by the [`ping` method](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1375) which formats the comment differently than either the [`html5_comment`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1441) method or the [`comment`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1393) method both of which create a much longer more complicated format than does the very minimal `ping` method.

You can kind-of guess what it does by the name of the variable, really, but when in doubt there is no better source of information than the source code itself.

Comment: _"there is no better source of information than the source code itself"_ is my favorite code-related quote (+1, of course)